# Iterate and sum elements of second list based on sequences in another list

Tags: python

I have two lists

```
l1 = [0,1,2,2,0,1,1,0]
l2 = [(0,2),(3,5),(6,8),(9,10),(11,15),(16,18),(19,20),(21,22)]
```

If there is a sequence of 1s and 2s in the first list, followed by 1 or 0, then I want it to return the first element of the tuple in the corresponding index in the second list and the second element of the tuple of the final 2. Same if it is just 1, followed by o or 1.

So the output here should be

```
out = [(3,10),(16,18),(19,20)]
```

This is what I have

```
for index, item in enumerate(true):
    if item == 0:
        continue
    elif item == 1 or item == 2:
        if true[index+1] == 0 or true[index+1] == 1:
            out.append(offsets[index])
        elif true[index+1] == 2:
            out.append((offsets[index][0], offsets[index+1][1]))
```

which results in

```
[(3, 8), (6, 10), (9, 10), (16, 18), (19, 20)]
```

Is there a more pythonic (and correct) way of approaching this?

Answer (score 1):

The less indexes you're going to use, the better

First list is a sequential access list. I'd iterate on it.
Second list is a random access list. You need indexes computed from the first list sequences to extract data

My proposal:

```
l1 = [0,1,2,2,0,1,1,0]
l2 = [(0,2),(3,5),(6,8),(9,10),(11,15),(16,18),(19,20),(21,22)]

# adding 0 handles the case where l1 doesn't end with 0
it = enumerate(l1+[0])

result = []

sv = 0
try:
    while True:
        if sv==1:
            fi,fv = si,sv
        else:
            while True:
                fi,fv = next(it)
                if fv:
                    break
        while True:
            si,sv = next(it)
            if sv == 0 or sv == 1:
                break
        result.append((l2[fi][0],l2[si-1][1]))
except StopIteration:
    pass

print(result)
```

output:

```
[(3, 10), (16, 18), (19, 20)]
```

I chose to manually iterate on the first list by creating an iterator out of the `enumerate` expression (which is already okay since `enumerate` is already an iterator). That way, I can iterate manually on the first index, then on the second index using inner `while True` loops and `next`, break when found.

And if the second value is a `1`, it stops the sequence but also needs to be reinjected in the iteration for next first value. It's not possible to do that with iterators, hence the test of previous `sv` and `si` values to avoid missing the third sequence.

Comment: This seems to work fine but if the final element of l1 is 1 instead of 0 then it doesn't return the matching tuple from l2

Comment: how about artificially adding 0 in the end no matter what then? or testing if ends with 0 else add it?

Comment: That seems to do the trick actually! Thanks man, I'll try it out in bigger lists to see if there are outliers I did not think of